# Convert All String Values to Lower/Uppercase in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use a list of string values in an if statement and convert any input given by the user to lowercase- the only way I can do this now is by making a list that includes all lowercase and uppercase values and then use the "in" and "not in" operators in the if statement. Here's my code:

```
yes = [
    "Y", "y", "yes", "YES"]
no = [
    "N", "n", "no", "NO"]


start = input("Hello there! Press 'y' to start, or 'n' to stop. ")
if start in yes:
    main()
elif start in no:
    print("Hope you can play some other time!")
```

There are other longer lists in the same program and this makes it very inconvenient to type different variations of the same word. Is there any way I can convert all values to lower/upper case either in the list itself, or in the if statement?

Comment: Use `start.lower()`.

Comment: Please do some searching before asking a question: this question is very easily answered through a search, as well as found in the [standard documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the builtin function `lower`:

```py
start = input("Hello there! Press 'y' to start, or 'n' to stop. ").lower()
if start in ['y', 'yes']:
    main()
elif start in ['n', 'no']:
    print("Hope you can play some other time!")
```

And if you want without the list at all, you can check only the first letter:

```py
start = input("Hello there! Press 'y' to start, or 'n' to stop. ").lower()
if start[0] == 'y':
    main()
elif start[0] == 'n':
    print("Hope you can play some other time!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inp = input('Enter: ').upper()
print(inp)
```

This will print the input in uppercase. user `lower()` to convert in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use [strtobool](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool).  This will obviate the need to `upper()`|`lower()` and will convert truthy values into `True`|`False` for you.

```
from distutils.util import strtobool
start = input("Hello there! Press 'y' to start, or 'n' to stop. ")
if strtobool(start):
    main()
else:
    print("Hope you can play some other time!")
```

*True values are y, yes, t, true, on and 1; false values are n, no, f, false, off and 0. Raises ValueError if val is anything else.*

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
start = input("Hello there! Press 'y' to start, or 'n' to stop. ").upper()[0]
    if start == "Y":
print("put main program here")
    else:
print("Hope you can play some other time!")
```